# importing python pdb library to jupyter notebook, returns ipdb prompt but doesnt show the exact error code line

Tags: python, import, breakpoints, pdb

I am writitng my python code in jupyter notebook. When i try to debug the code by importing pdb library and writing pdb.set_trace() in the code and running it, I just get ipdb prompt which allows me to print and see variable values but doesn't let me see breakpoints and exact code line which has the error. I am unable to use n,c functions.

I have tried using breakpoint() and %debug but its the same, i still dont get the interactive bit where i can run the code step by step and see where the error is.

Comment: You seem to be trying console or script-based approaches inside a running `.ipynb` and expecting them to work the same. That isn't how Jupyter works **typically**. Jupyter is cell based & has a 'state'. Most of the time the one cell doesn't know about the other. You've noted that you can query the current namespace. JupyterLab has a debugger built in, see [here](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/debugger.html) about its features & **kernel needs**. Alternatively you can run a script from inside a notebook or in the Jupyter terminal with IPython using `%run script_name_here.py`.